# ISServerExec.exe crash when executing from SQL schedule job

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

I have ETL packages that works fine in Visual Studio 2019

When we deploy and run it from SQL Server Agent, it gives the error below

Additional info: the package is set to "Encrypt sensitive with password" and we set the connection password in the SQL Job step settings

Faulting application name: ISServerExec.exe, version: 14.0.1000.169, time stamp: 0x599ccc42

Faulting module name: **OraOLEDB11.DLL, version: 11.2.0.1, time stamp: 0x4b9a19db

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x000000000002c000

Faulting process id: 0x3954

Faulting application start time: 0x01d642753af07699

Faulting application path: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\ISServerExec.exe

Faulting module path: C:\oracle\oracleclient64\bin\OraOLEDB11.DLL

Report Id: 0db0c583-e4aa-4dec-89f5-509f3969595c

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

---

**UPDATE**
Tried executing package from Integration Services Catalog in SSMS but also failed, the detailed error is "cannot acquire connection from connection manager"
It looks something related to password in the oracle database connection

Comment: Is it only the package with Oracle components in it that fails or every package? Is TNSNames and all that nonsense configured properly? Are you running the package in the same bit (32 vs 64) as the installed drivers?

Comment: Yes 
1) Only packages with Oracle components fail, other packages that connects to local SQL Server with windows authentication works fine
2) TNSNames is configured propertly (it also works when being executed in VS)
3) I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit (in the properties > debugging in the VS project) but the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, we found the solution.

It works when we changed the runtime in SQL Server Job Step properties to 32-bit